# Validate multiple Nigerian mobile phone number formats

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match, phone-number

How do I match multiple phone number length and format in regex?

```
^(?:080|070|081|\+?234)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){(8|10)}$
```

This is my code:

```
if (!preg_match("^(?:080|070|081|\+?234)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){(8)}$", $mobile)) {
    // valid mobile number
}
```

I want to support the following number formats:

- `+2347036756899`
- `+234-7036-756899`
- `07036756899`
- `08036756899`

https://regex101.com/r/07TLhR/1

Comment: @Scuzzy sorry i didn't understand what you asked me

Comment: Please explain your requirements.

Comment: `^(?:080|070|081|\+?234)(\d{8,10}|-\d{4}-\d{6})$` filter out the dashes later, don't go nuts with capturing groups. I'd say its your look ahead `(?!.-.-)` that's messing with you?

Comment: @Scuzzy it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern:

```
^(?:0|\+234)-?(?:80|70|81)-?\d{2}-?\d{6}$
```

- `(?:0|\+234)` your country code or zero
- `-?` optional dash
- `(?:70|80|81)` your valid prefix
- `\d{2}` continued by 2 digits
- `-?` optional dash again
- `\d{6}` the last 6 numbers

test here:

https://regex101.com/r/chGyQD/1

Comment: This allows a phone number to start with `0-80`, but that is not asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern explanation:

```
^                #match start of string
(?:              #non-capturing group
   \+234(-)?     #match literal +, then 234, then an optional hyphen <-|
   |             #OR                                                   |
   0             #match 0                                              |
)                #end non-capturing group                              |
(?:[78]0|81)     #match 70, 80, or 81                                  |
\d{2}            #match two digits                                     |
(?(1)-|)         #conditionally require hyphen if hyphen after 234   ->|
\d{6}            #match 6 digits
$                #match end of string
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YkTVJ))

```
$tests = [
    '+2347036756899',
    '+234-7036-756899',
    '+2347036-756899',
    '+234-7036756899',
    '07036756899',
    '0-7036756899',
    '07036-756899',
    '08036756899',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    printf(
        "%20s : %s\n",
        $test,
        preg_match('/^(?:\+234(-)?|0)(?:[78]0|81)\d{2}(?(1)-|)\d{6}$/', $test) ? '✅' : '❌'
    ); 
}
```

Output:

```
  +2347036756899 : ✅
+234-7036-756899 : ✅
 +2347036-756899 : ❌
 +234-7036756899 : ❌
     07036756899 : ✅
    0-7036756899 : ❌
    07036-756899 : ❌
     08036756899 : ✅
```